# SSMS How to find the Connection name

Tags: sql-server, ssms

How do you return the connection name via TSQL? This is visible in SSMS via the properties window. For example if you have a DNS alias "ProductionServer" for a machine named "SRVR0001" and further have a local server registration for this named "Live Production" and then

1) Open a new query providing a Server name of "ProductionServer" then the connection name will be "ProductionServer"
2) Right click the local registration and select new query, the connection name will be "Live Production"

And of course in both instances `select @@SERVERNAME` will return SRVR0001.

This is similar, but different, to these questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088151/how-to-find-server-name-of-sql-server-management-studio
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129861/how-can-i-query-the-name-of-the-current-sql-server-database-instance

I anticipate the answer may well be that this is a local property held by SSMS, and thus can not be returned by TSQL run on SQL Server.

Comment: >>>I anticipate the answer may well be that this is a local property held by SSMS<<< And indeed there is no interest to server to know how did you name your connection or local registration, so only your client tool may know this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment left by user [sepupic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/124448/sepupic) is correct:

> And indeed there is no interest to server to know how did you name your connection or local registration, so only your client tool may know this

The only places I might have expected to see this would be the "connection" related DMVs, for instance if SQL Server kept track of the connection name used to connect to it (similar to how it keeps track of the client host name, set options used, etc).

However, it's not present in any of the main ones I checked:

- `sys.dm_exec_connections`
- `sys.dm_exec_requests`
- `sys.dm_exec_sessions`

And this makes sense, especially with registrations where the client has to translate those names before creating the connection anyway.

Comment: Indeed, I expected this to be the case, but I was interested to know if otherwise. Answer accepted, but obviously I'll change that if someone comes along to correct us!